# State of the art in voice recognition

Tags: computer-vision, emotional-intelligence, facial-recognition, voice-recognition, audio-processing

In the media there's lot of talk about **face** recognition, mainly with respect to identifying faces (= assigning to persons). Less attention is paid to the recognition of facially expressed **emotions** but there's a lot of research done into this direction, too. Even less attention is paid to the recognition of facially expressed emotions of a single person (which could be much more detailed) - even though this would be a very interesting topic.

What holds for faces does similarily hold for **voices**. With the help of artifical intelligence voices can be identified (= assigned to persons) and emotions as expressed by voice can be recognized - on a general and on an individual's level.

My general question goes into another direction: As huge progress has been made in **visual** scene analysis ("what is **seen** in this scene?") there has probably been some progress made in **auditory** scene analysis: "What is **heard** in this scene?"

My specific question is: Are there test cases and results where some AI software was given some auditory data with a lot of "voices" and could tell **how many voices there were**?

As a rather easy specific test case consider some [Gregorian chant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_chant) sung in perfect unison. (See also [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/94640/the-discriminating-power-of-experienced-listeners).)